# Errors compiling Firefox on Debian

Tags: firefox, debian, compile

I want compile Firefox on Debian so I create .mozconfig like:

```
mk_add_options MOZ_OBJDIR=@TOPSRCDIR@/ff-dbg
ac_add_options --enable-application=browser
```

...and now use this command to compile ( create make ):

```
 ./configure
```

...but I get this error:

```
configure: error: Library requirements (libnotify >= 0.4) not met; consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if your libraries are in a nonstandard prefix so pkg-config can find them.
```

...so search in repo:

```
i   libnotify-bin                  - sends desktop notifications to a notifica
i A libnotify0.4-cil               - CLI library for desktop notifications    
i A libnotify1                     - sends desktop notifications to a notifica
v   libnotify1-gtk2.10             -
```

What can I do to get this compiled?

Comment: have you installed libnotify1-dev or it's variants?

Comment: Do not use "configure"! That will just break the compiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install the `*-dev` packages if you want to compile something against a library.

In your case it would be one or more of these:

```
$ apt-cache search libnotify dev
libnotify-cil-dev - CLI library for desktop notifications
libnotifymm-dev - C++ binding for libnotify (development files)
libnotify-dev - sends desktop notifications to a notification daemon
```

I have Ubuntu 10.04, your results may vary.